# the upper and lower Riemann integrals have the same partition P?

Tags: real-analysis

If a function is Riemann-integrable, by definition, it means that the upper Riemann integral equal to the lower Riemann integral.
$$\inf\ U(p,f)=\sup\ L(p,f)$$

My question: Do they have the same partition $p$? by intuition, I think it is the same partition $p$, but I hardly find the proof.

Comment: Those p need not be same.On the LHS,you are taking infinimum over all partitions and in RHS the supremum over all such partitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As general rule, they will not only NOT be the same partition, but a partition such that 
$\inf\ U(p,f)=U(p,f)$ may not exist, as it usually happens that as partitions get finer the upper sum gets lower(and viceversa for the lower one)

Comment: "You're confused, as general rule" That makes it sound like the OP is confused as a general rule.

Comment: @zhw That's not what I meant. I'll edit it. I'm not a native English speaker and thus subtleties can be lost on me

Comment: I know it's not what you meant. But it's funny.